# sending a parameter to a function returns Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am new to react and redux. I am trying to send a parameter via react router and receive it in a component which is responsible for managing reducer and action to hold and update states. Here is my class which my issue happens there:

```
import React from "react";
import {connect} from "react-redux";

import  {getStoriesAction2} from '../../actions/StoryBoardAction2';
import {StoryBoard} from '../composers/story-board/StoryBoard';
class StoryBoardStateManager2 extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <StoryBoard storyId={this.props.params.id} stories={this.props.stories2} getStories={()=> this.props.getStories2()}/>
        </div>


    );
}
}

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
 return {
    stories2: state.storyBoardReducer2
};
};

 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getStories2:() => {
        dispatch(getStoriesAction2());

    }
  };
 };

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)  (StoryBoardStateManager2);
```

in the above storyId={this.props.params.id} is getting the parameter sent via router which works perfectly fine but I need to send this id as a parameter to this function: getStoriesAction2 so I need to change the function to the following :

```
getStoriesAction2(this.props.params.id)
```

As soon as I add the above params I get the follwoing error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
```

which basically says that cannot read params of undefined. So how can I pass this.props.params.id to the above function? can anyone help to find where my problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your mapDispatchToProps this way:

```
 const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    getStories2:(id) => {
        dispatch(getStoriesAction2(id));

    }
  };
 };
```

and than you can change getStories2 binding:

```
 getStories={()=> this.props.getStories2(this.props.params.id)}
```